# Multiple selection on iPad

Tags: touch-screen, multi-selection, ipad

Normally we use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-select to select multiple rows for doing a batch operation in a search result page.

How can we perform the same in case of iPad or other touch devices?

Putting in check boxes can be an alternative. Is there another solution which I might not be aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's something known as a **Selection Mode** in Mobile devices that can be triggered by **long pressing one row/ item/ element**.

This mode brings different actions on the screen as well as allowing to select multiple items or single row/ item/ element with just one tap as long as you are in that mode.

[image: Gmail Selection Mode]

This avoids you to have visible check boxes on either side of the UI unless you're in selection mode and saves that Checkbox screen estate along with the padding required for it.

So, yes, having a different mode for Selection with different actions once you're in that mode is a good way to approach this.

Comment: On iOS you generally click a button at the right top (In Photo's for example it's called: Select). Then you can just tap every photo you want. Then you can do an action on all selected items (like delete). The Select button changes into: Cancel while doing this.

Answer (score 3):

**long-press** - for first item selection

**touch** - for subsequent selections

---

***According to Google***

https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/selection.html#

> The global gesture to select data is a **long-press**, a touch or
>   mousedown that’s held in the same position for a moment. A two-finger
>   touch may also trigger selection on touch devices.

---

> **Item Selection**
>
> Once an initial selection is made, it can be altered through user
>   actions:

- > Touch a selected item to deselect it. Touch an unselected
  >   item to select it.